# VSCode maven proj package org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication does not exist

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, pom.xml

I am trying to start a simple Hello World Project on my Mac.

Using VScode, I downloaded Maven and Java extensions. After opening a maven project, when running the application.java, I get message:

```
{
"resource": "Projects/***/backend/src/main/java/com/***/backend/BackendApplication.java",
"owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
"code": "compiler.err.doesnt.exist",
"severity": 8,
"message": "package org.springframework.boot does not exist",
"startLineNumber": 3,
"startColumn": 8,
"endLineNumber": 3,
"endColumn": 50
}
```

Here is my application.java:

```
package com.iz.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.iz</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>backend</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I found on the internet that dependency

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
```

might solve it. However, it already exists in my pom file.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following two ways:

1. In VS Code, open Command Palette and Search **Maven: add a dependency** to re-download these packages and rebuild the project;
2. Download these jar packages from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) locally and [add them to referenced libraries](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar) manually.

**[EDIT]**

Add the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then rebuild the project.

Comment: @l.zv. I've updated my answer, have a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is working now. Any chance you can take a look on that too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673496/requestmapping-spring-boot-doesnt-function-as-expected

Comment: Glad my answer helps you, you may mark it for more people to reach this solution. About your another question, i'll have a try.

Answer (score 0):

If the scope of the dependency is `runtime`, you cannot use it in your code.

It needs to be `compile` for that.

Comment: I tried to change the scope to compile. Still get same result. Actually there is a red under-line in the application.java. lines 3,4. means my vsCode has issues with those 2 imports..

Comment: How you ran the `application.java`? Using a maven project you need to hit:
`mvn clean package`
`java -jar <path/to/jar>`