# Spring Files.readString() does not work with Maven set to Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, file, bufferedreader

Trying to write a simple application that reads a file and prints out the file's content. I read that Java 11 has Java.io.file library so I used it. I created a .txt file locally.

My main class looks like this:

```
package com.iz.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.Content;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);        
    
        Path filePath = Paths.get("/Users/iz/Proj/backend/src/testFile.txt");

        try
        {
            String content = Files.readString(filePath);

            System.out.println(content);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When running

```
mvn clean install
```

to compile and build a jar file, I get a compilation error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project backend: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/proj/backend/src/main/java/com/iz/backend/BackendApplication.java:[26,34] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Is your maven configured to use the right version of Java? You can check with `mvn --version`. Also, it doesn't look your readString is on line 26 or am I wrong?

Comment: I am using Apache Maven 3.6.3 and in the pom file I defined Java 11

Comment: Where are you executing clean install from?

Comment: The fact that your pom.xml specifies java 11 doesn't mean it will use java 11. If you haven't installed java 11 or your java home is pointing to an older release maven will use that.

Comment: What does `javac -version` return for you?

Comment: Upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin version cause you are using an ancient version...  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: code works for me; just drop your testFile.txt in the project root, and then: Path filePath = Paths.get("testFile.txt");

Comment: @Sled javac 1.8.0_275

Comment: @HellishHeat The file in under src folder. What do you mean by "project root" ?

Comment: at the same level as the src folder; this is often referred to as the project root. So, up one level .

Comment: @l.zv then it looks like you have Java 1.8 installed so while Maven can run, it won't be able to compile Java 11 code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try this in your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, with the following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: for some reason I cannot add the spring-boot-starter dependency. It cant read it.

Comment: yes- dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar is missing